# Error in submitting the es-injector.flux topology

Tags: stormcrawler

I have setup the stormcrawler project using this medium story https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/web-scraping-and-indexing-with-stormcrawler-and-elasticsearch-a105cb9c02ca, but when I tried to submit the es-injector.flux, then I recevied this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find a suitable 
constructor for class 'com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.StringTabScheme' with 
    arguments '[DISCOVERED]'.
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildObject(FluxBuilder.java:358)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildComponents(FluxBuilder.java:421)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildTopology(FluxBuilder.java:101)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.Flux.runCli(Flux.java:158)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.Flux.main(Flux.java:103)
```

The command that I run is:

```
storm jar target/project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  org.apache.storm.flux.Flux --local es- 
injector.flux
```

Can someone please tell me what does it mean and how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [latest ES tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kpJLPdhvLw&t=1199s) is probably a better starting point, I'd recommend that you use it instead.